# Count exploded string from mysqli DB using php

Tags: php, mysqli, count, explode

Have a problem with counting some data from mysqli database using php. But it's not counting anything and display only 11111. Must display a sum of usd. field. Please help me to solve this problem.

Counting data have this:

```
115 pc. | 105 ml | 225 usd.
125 pc. | 130 ml | 345 usd.
```

and so on.

So i do like this:

```
<?php 

$qry2 = "SELECT (howmuch) FROM $tabname WHERE send_ok='ok' ORDER BY $oid DESC";
$howmuch_result = $con->query($qry2);

$jimmy = explode(" | ", $how['howmuch'])[2];
$jimmy_n = str_replace(" usd.", " ", $jimmy);


while ($how = $howmuch_result->fetch_assoc()) {

 echo count($jimmy_n);
 } 

 ?>
```

Comment: `SELECT SUM(FIELD_NAME_HERE) AS howmuch FROM`...

Comment: Are you actually storing amounts with their units together in the same column? You should normalize your DB and split them into separate columns and tables.

Comment: @FrankerZ... thank you but not working... maybe i do something wrong... please give an example

Answer (score -1):

Correct order of operators:

```
$qry2 = "SELECT (howmuch) FROM $tabname WHERE send_ok='ok' ORDER BY $oid DESC";
$howmuch_result = $con->query($qry2) or die (mysqli_error($con));

// Sum
$sum = 0;
while ($how = $howmuch_result->fetch_assoc()) {
    $jimmy = explode(" | ", $how['howmuch'])[2];
    $jimmy_n = str_replace(" usd.", " ", $jimmy);
    echo $jimmy_n;

    $sum += $jimmy_n;
} 
echo $sum;
```

Comment: Thank you but i can't see "count" action in your example. Your script just display all data without sum.

Comment: You can also use `fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC)` and count the returned elements in the array, then loop with `foreach`

Comment: I would also strongly recommend to remove the debugging line `or die (mysqli_error($con))`. Use exceptions instead: `mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);`

Comment: @u_mulder... sorry but your update do nothing just cut "usd." from string but not summed ((

Comment: @Dharman... please give an example about fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC).. because i don't understand you

Comment: You can't write echo $sum, really?